# Using Cell Arrays in Interpolants in Matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, cell, interpolation, cell-array

I have a griddedInterpolant F and some of the input variables are in a cell array form. As an example, this is how I created the interpolant F:

```
[x,y,z] = ndgrid(-5:1:5);
t = x+y+z;
mycell  = {x,y};
F = griddedInterpolant(mycell{:},z,t);
```

In reality, the size of the cell array *mycell* changes each time I run the code, and that's why I figured I have to use a cell array as an input. Now I'd like to call this function with the same input structure. When I have a single row for each input, everything works fine as in the following example:

```
testcell = {1,3};
F(testcell{:},5)

ans =

     9
```

However, when I'd like the inputs in a vector form, the interpolant doesn't work and I get the following error:

```
testcell = {1,3; 2, 4};
F(testcell{:,:},[5;1])
```

> Error using griddedInterpolant/subsref
>
> Invalid arguments specified in evaluating the interpolant.

Because I don't know the dimensions (number of columns) in my actual cell array, I can not break *testcell* apart. What is the right way to use the interpolant F in this case? I could, of course, use a for loop but this approach might be very time consuming due to the large number of data that I have.

Comment: what are you trying to do here? not knowing the dimensions you can make a function instead of working with cell arrays....

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: If I understood what you are trying to do here I'd try to answer. Begin with, "I want to interpolate a 3D data set of..." ....

Comment: Let me be clearer. I don't know how many variables go in to griddedInterpolant as inputs to create the interpolant F. It is a blackbox to me. I have two functions, first to create the interpolant, which I don't have any problem with, and second to call the interpolant, where my problem lies. If F is made out of 3D data, the latter function does know it is 3D data but I cannot explicitly code it as F(x1, x2, x3) because *I* don't know it is 3D. I only have a cell of x that contains {x1, x2, x3} where each are nx1 vector themselves. So I'd like to call F for n cases at once without a for loop.

Comment: I dont think you can do this without a loop, and i fail to see how you don't even know the dimensionality of what you want to interpolate in advance...  (in your example you did use x,y,z=ndgrid... )

Comment: So each time you should define new `t` and `F`.

Comment: rahnema1, yes that is what my function automatically does.

Bla, the reason why I shouldn't care about the dimensionality comes from automation. The code must work with any dimension I feed in. I gave the example of x,y,z = ngrid(...) above because the code does know what the dimensions are, and change the grids accordingly. It is a very simple logic, actually. I can't automate the process otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer to my problem in another forum. Apparently, this problem is solved just by slightly fixing how *testcell* is defined at the end as such:

```
testcell = {[1;2]; [3; 4]};
```